# MSSQL -How to operate a second sp from a first sp BUT not to stop the first one

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Helo Friends,
I'm inside a first stored procedure, and from the inside of this first procedure, I want to execute a second stored procedure.
Ofcourse I can write a simple 'execute' command.

The problem is that the second procedure has a long duration, and I don't want the first procedure to wait until the second one is finished.

I simply ask the first Procedure to keep running independently also after it activates the second Stored Procedure - I mean I need the first procedure to forget from the second Procedure after it called it.

The data base is MSSQL 2008

I will appreciate any help.
     David

Comment: You are looking for asynchronous stored procedures.  Any support a database has for such constructs is highly database-specific, so you should mention the database you are using.

Comment: right . The Database is MSSQL 2008

Comment: If you don;t need the second one to be complete before taking other steps, why not just make it the last step?

Comment: @user2746711 . . . In SQL Server, you can do this using queues and the service broker (start here to understand it http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345108(v=sql.90).aspx).  I don't know of a simpler method.

Comment: Or you can kick off a job via agent

Comment: If I make it the last step - the first procedure still need to wait untill the second one to finished. I want the first one to finish without to wait the second one to finished.

Comment: Gordon and Yuriy thanks, but these are the only ways? I thought there is a simple command you know...like in batchFile...